# How to get Clementine to play AAC files (on Windows)?

Tags: windows-7, audio, plugins, media-player, aac

I just installed the [Clementine audio player](https://www.clementine-player.org/). I like it, but it doesn't play my `.aac` files.  [This Ubuntu forum post suggests](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2133844) this is due to decoder licensing issues, and necessitates installing the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package. Of course, this only works on Ubuntu. What about Windows (7)? Is there a plugin I can use? I couldn't find one. The Preferences dialog was also not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but did you try the Windows 7 Codec Pack - http://download.cnet.com/Windows-7-Codec-Pack/3000-13632_4-10965840.html

Comment: Oh, I have a codec pack installed - I use K-Lite Mega Codec Pack, which includes filters & codecs for handling AAC files. Do you think the codec pack you linked to has something special Clementine would like?